# Jquery datetime picker plugin?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using this plugin:

http://tedserbinski.com/jcalendar/index.html

The plugin is supposed to accept a user defined startdate, but I cant manage to get it to work.

This is the header of the js file:

var _drawCalendar = function(dateIn, a, day, month, year) {

```
  var today = new Date();


    if (dateIn == undefined) {
        // start from this month.
        d = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1);
        year.val(today.getFullYear());
        month.val(today.getMonth()+1);
        day.val(today.getDate());

    }
    else {
        // start from the passed in date
        d = dateIn;
      d.setDate(1);
    }
```

And i am calling the calendar plug with the following line, that actually is missing something. I have tried hundreds of diffrent code snippets, but I have gived up :(

$('fieldset.jcalendar').jcalendar();

Best regards, Joakim

Answer (score 2):

Any particular reason you aren't using the [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) that comes with [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)? The page you linked even says that the project has been superceded by jQuery UI.